# How to extract keys from pfx file using OpenSSL in Python?

Tags: python, xml, openssl

I need to sign an `xml` with the `certificate` and `key` from a `pfx` file.

In other words, I have a pfx file, from where I need to extract the `pem` an `key` to sign my `xml`.

I've found this script to extract the pen and key from pfx, but is giving me error:

```
import OpenSSL.crypto


pfx_path = 'D:\\facturacion_electronica\\cetificado_prueba\\llama.pfx'


pfx_password = 'caballo123'

def load_public_key(pfx_path, pfx_password):
        ''' Read the public key and return as PEM encoded '''

        # print('Opening:', pfx_path)
        with open(pfx_path, 'rb') as f:
                pfx_data = f.read()

        # print('Loading PFX contents:')
        pfx = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx_data, pfx_password)

        public_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(
                OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
                p12.get_certificate().get_pubkey())

        print(public_key)

        return public_key


load_public_key(pfx_path, pfx_password)
```

**Error:**

```
python openssl.py
openssl.py:17: DeprecationWarning: str for passphrase is no longer accepted, use bytes
  pfx = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx_data, pfx_password)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openssl.py", line 28, in <module>
    load_public_key(pfx_path, pfx_password)
  File "openssl.py", line 21, in load_public_key
    p12.get_certificate().get_pubkey())
NameError: name 'p12' is not defined
```

**After extracting the pem and key, I would use this to sign the XML:**

```
from lxml import etree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier

passwd = 'caballo123'
cd = 'D:\\facturacion_electronica\\cetificado_prueba\\'


data_to_sign = "<Test/>"
cert = open("example.pem").read()
key = open("example.key").read()
root = etree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root).signed_xml
```

Comment: Your password is a string. Use bytes instead `pfx_password = b'caballo123'` Note the code that you are using is for Google P12 and not PFX. `p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(data, p12_password)`

Comment: @JohnHanley ty. in the original code, there is not a `p12_password` variable, only `pfx_passowrd`. Where does it come from?

Comment: Change the name. The password is just a byte string. The point is that you need to know what type of files you are loading. In your case, the code is for Google P12 service accounts.

Comment: I have written a number of articles on credentials such as P12, PFX, JSON key files. My articles usually have working source code: https://www.jhanley.com/

Comment: @JohnHanley I'll look into your webpage. Just a question, why did you mention Google P12 servicies? Don't understand. I've change: `pfx_password` to `p12_password = b'caballo123'`.  But still getting: `public_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate().get_pubkey())
NameError: name 'p12' is not defined`

Comment: because PFX is a different format. You need to use the correct code for the format of the credentials (certificates). Start by improving your question on what you are doing, what you want, etc. There are lots of examples for processing these files on the Internet.

Comment: I've looked and the most promising is the answer you wrote. I'll try to simplify my question here: need to sign an xml (any xml) with the key and certificate from the pfx file I have. I'd appreaciate if you could write an answer on this.

Comment: @JohnHanley reading you page, I think I've found a solution. Sorry for any inconvinience.

Comment: @JohnHanley would you mind checking this other related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585385/how-to-generate-the-hash-in-base64-for-dsdigestvalue-dssignaturevalue-and-ds?noredirect=1#comment105337491_59585385  

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer on John Hanley personal page:

https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-extracting-private-key-from-service-account-p12-credentials/

```py
    import OpenSSL.crypto
    import os

    pfx_cert = 'D:\\facturacion_electronica\\cetificado_prueba\\llama.pfx'
    pfx_password = b'caballo123'

    ###########################################################    
    # Version 1.00
    # Date Created: 2018-12-21
    # Last Update:  2018-12-21
    # https://www.jhanley.com
    # Copyright (c) 2018, John J. Hanley
    # Author: John Hanley
    ###########################################################

    # Convert a Google P12 (PFX) service account into private key and certificate.
    # Convert an SSL Certifcate (PFX) into private key, certificate and CAs.

    def write_CAs(filename, p12):
        # Write the Certificate Authorities, if any, to filename

        if os.path.exists(filename):
            os.remove(filename)

        ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()

        if ca is None:
            return

        print('Creating Certificate CA File:', filename)

        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            for cert in ca:
                f.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))

    def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password, pkey_path, pem_path, pem_ca_path):
        '''
        Decrypt the P12 (PFX) file and create a private key file and certificate file.

        Input:
            pfx_path    INPUT: This is the Google P12 file or SSL PFX certificate file
            pfx_password    INPUT: Password used to protect P12 (PFX)
            pkey_path   INPUT: File name to write the Private Key to
            pem_path    INPUT: File name to write the Certificate to
            pem_ca_path INPUT: File name to write the Certificate Authorities to
        '''

        print('Opening:', pfx_path)
        with open(pfx_path, 'rb') as f_pfx:
            pfx = f_pfx.read()

        print('Loading P12 (PFX) contents:')
        p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, pfx_password)

        print('Creating Private Key File:', pkey_path)
        with open(pkey_path, 'wb') as f:
            # Write Private Key
            f.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))

        print('Creating Certificate File:', pem_path)
        with open(pem_path, 'wb') as f:
            # Write Certificate
            f.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))

        # Google P12 does not have certifiate authorities but SSL PFX certificates do
        write_CAs(pem_ca_path, p12)

    # Start here

    pfx_to_pem(
        pfx_cert,         # Google Service Account P12 file
        pfx_password,     # P12 file password
        'llama.key',      # Filename to write private key
        'llama_cert.pem', # Filename to write certificate
        'llama_ca.pem')   # Filename to write CAs if present
```